# AJAX is opening pages

Tags: ajax

Whenever i run the following code it opens the site www.mnemonics.com which i don't want it to. Any reason why its doing that? trying other domains doesn't open them.. just wonder why this site in particular is doing it.

As for why im running it... call it experimenting.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: false,
        url: "http://www.mnemonics.com/",
        success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(responseData.status);
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(responseData.status);
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("complete");
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What status code is the site sending?

Comment: how about `url: "http://www.mnemonics.com/"`?

Comment: @NickBailey it runs both the "error" and "complete" function and spits out a 200 http code.

Comment: @1010 isn't that already the url I'm AJAX'ing to?